# How to double check password in serializer of django restframework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to double check `password` and `repeated_password` sent from front-end.

```
{"user_data":{"user_name":"jim", "email":"jim@google.com", "password":"ddd","repeat_password":"ssss","role_list":[1,2,3]}}
```

And I add a validator in my serilazer as :

```
# serilazers.py

class SUser(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    repeat_password = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    role_list = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user_name

    def get_role_list(self, obj):
        role_queryset = MRole.objects.filter(group__in=obj.groups.all())
        return [
            {
                "role_id": role.id,
                "role_name": role.name,
            }
            for role in role_queryset
        ]

    def validate(self, attrs):
        print(attrs)
        # OrderedDict([('user_name', 'jim'), ('email', 'jim@163.com'), ('password', 'ddd')]) there's only password here , 
        # why repeat_password not appear?

        if value.get('password') == value.get('repeat_password'):
            return value
        raise exceptions.ValidationError('need same passwd')



    class Meta:
        model = MUser
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'user_name',
                  'email', 'password', 'repeat_password',
                  'groups', 'is_active',
                  'role_list']


# models.py

class Muser(AbstractUser):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=150,unique=False)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'User'
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name = 'user'
```

to validate data

```
user_data = request.data.get("user_data")
serializer_for_user = SUser(data={
                    **user_data
                })
serializer_for_user.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

But when I try to validate the data, I can't get `repeat_password` in my validate method of serilazer.

How can I do my double check work of pwd?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing `read_only=True`

```
repeat_password = serializers.CharField()
```

In your case, I think you should go for `Serializer`, not `ModelSerializer` because toggling the value of `read_only` will always give you errors.

- If you try with `read_only=True` then the field will be ignored.
- If you try it with `read_only=False` then it will try to save that in your database and will raise the error that this field does not exist in the database.

---

> Read-only fields are included in the API output, but should not be
> included in the input during create or update operations. **Any
> `read_only` fields that are incorrectly included in the serializer
> input will be ignored.**
>
> Set this to `True` to ensure that the field is used when serializing a
> representation, but is not used when creating or updating an instance
> during deserialization.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#read_only

Comment: Thanks for replying， but I got `Muser' object has no attribute 'repeat_password` error after removing it , as my `Muser` doesn't have field `repeat_password` and `repeat_password` is only for check use. How to make it ?

Comment: can you tell more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to do a double check with `password` and `repeat_password` and then save `password` only in my `user` table.